# Why is my bitmap being re-sized in Android?

Tags: android, resize, bitmap

Very new to Android development, and I am importing a bitmap that is 799 in width.  However, when I bring the bitmap into Android, it is saying the bitmap is now 533 in width.  Is there a reason for that?

Here's the code I'm using:

Bitmap texture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);

Preferably, I'd like to have the image be the same size as when I originally created it.  That way I know ahead of time what I'm dealing with rather than checking again what the code has done to the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

into your manifest, see if that fixes the problem without the drawable-nodpi folder.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help here.  That worked too!  I also renamed my drawable folder to just "drawable" generically.

Comment: Hmm...also removed the code you recommended and it still worked.  So, maybe it was just that my folder was originally named "drawable-hdpi"

Comment: Depends on what device you're testing it on. If your drawables are in the drawable-hdpi folder, and you're testing on an mdpi device, they will be scaled down. If you put the anyDensity line in there, I believe that disables the automatic scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...well, I think I solved my own problem though I don't comprehend it.  I changed my image to be stored in the source folder res/drawable-nodpi, and now there's no scaling.

Guess I have to investigate what those different folders mean and how to deal with it in my code.